# Perl Copy files from several sub-directory paths to one directory path

Tags: perl, file, recursion, directory, copy

How can I copy .txt files from several sub-directory paths to one directory path and retain the same name for each .txt file in the destination directory path.

Here's my code. And it doesn't work for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Copy;

my @a = glob("/aim/original/*/*.txt"); #source 

print "@a\n";
my $newfile = "/aim/duplicate/"; #destination directory
foreach (@a)
  {
   copy ("$_", $newfile) or die "Cannot copy files $!";
  }
```

I also tried this code but it wasn't working as well

```
perl -MFile::Copy=copy -e'copy($_, "/aim/duplicate/") for </aim/original/*/*.txt>'
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?  What does it do wrong?

Comment: Where does `@name ` come from?

Comment: files are not copied to the destination folder